# Remove already selected items from autocomplete (using typeahead, bootstrap-tokeninput and json)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, typeahead.js, jquery-tokeninput

I've done an autocomplete list using typeahead (0.9.3) and bootstrap-tokeninput.

The use case is to select many recipients in a single input. (For example: when you select many users to send them a message on facebook)

Here what I've done so far (using rails):

#### conversation controller

```
def new
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

#### conversations.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#conversation_recipients").tokenfield({
    typeahead: {
      prefetch: "/conversations/new.json",
      valueKey: 'username',
      template: '<img src="{{avatar.url}}"</img><span>{{username}}</span>',
      engine: Hogan
    }
  });
})
```

What I am trying to do is to remove already selected items from the @users list.

I don't know if I have to do it by removing selected users with js using the bootstrap-tokeninput Events api (maybe the beforeCreateToken event could be useful) and manipulating the json on this event or if there is another way to do it...

Many thanks for your suggestion.